# How to display a video behind gui on mobile with Unity3D

Tags: c#, android, ios, video, unity-game-engine

Is it possibile to play a video, mp4 or other format, behind the GUI in Unity3D for mobile?

Using class [MovieTexture](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MovieTexture.html) it works on desktop, unfortunately MovieTextures aren't supported on iOS/Android.

And [Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie.html) only plays the movie in full screen.

There is some other method?

(or a solid plugin)

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
Vuforia [Unity - How do I create a simple VideoPlayback app](https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/faq/unity-how-do-i-create-simple-videoplayback-app)

You just can put your UI in front of the video.